# Вопрос про работу с кириллицей (UTF-8) в C++ | Linux

Tags: c++, utf-8, locale

**Вводная**

Допустим есть файл сохранённый в UTF8. Читать я его могу исключительно std::ifstream (без std::wifstream).

После прочтения файла, я хочу иметь возможность итерироваться по utf-8 символам, и даже сравнивать их

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < utf8String.size(); i++) {
    if (utf8String[i] == 'ф') {
        //...
    }
}
```

Как мне этого добиться? Вероятно для этого потребуется сконструировать строку, **std::wstring**, в linux она конструируется из **wchar_t**, которые занимают 4 байта.

Тогда вопрос в следующем: как сделать конструирование из **std::string** - которая хранит какой-то utf8 текст - строки **std::wstring**.

Самый первый вариант который приходит в голову: `wstring wstr(str.begin(), str.end());` К сожалению не подойдет.

Чтобы понять почему не подойдёт потребуется класс, который показывает битовое содержимое вот он ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/ckkmbaCq))

Если посмотреть на utf8 строку "добро", хранимую в string то например 'д' будет представлено так **11010000 10110100** всё верно.

А вот символ 'д' из наивно сконструированной строки занимает целых 2 элемента wchar_t
**11010000 11111111 11111111 11111111 10110100 11111111 11111111 11111111** и вообще не похож на utf-8.

Я могу объяснить почему он стал таким, но не будем (вкратце это от того что wchar_t=char а char<0 для любых широких символов + порядок байт на машине)

Я нашел что string -> wstring можно сделать [linux.org.ru](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/13177014) Но в моём gcc нет такого хедера как `#include <codecvt>`

Решил сделать сам конструирование из string в wstring как-то так ([pastebin](https://pastebin.com/egtYCwSa))

Теперь вопрос ко знатокам, я не разу не работал плотно с локалью, поэтому к своему стыду не знаю всех тонкостей, воспринимаю работу с локалью так как описано здесь https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale

т.е. просто нужно вставить в код

```
locale::global(std::locale("") );
wcout.imbue(std::locale());
```

Понимаю что это даст не более чем какие-то "национальные преобразования" например даты, денежных форматов, дробных форматов. Но именно слова закодированные в utf8 никак не должны затрагиваться манипуляциями с локалями. Верно? Ведь для этого и существует utf8, чтобы однозначно представлять символы разных стран кодом. Код буквы 'Д' внезависимости от любых манипуляций с локакалью (или отсутствием этих манипуляций) есть **1101000010110100** Правильно?

Вроде бы да, но почему-то ручное преобразовние не работает. После работы этой ф-ии букве 'д' будет соответствовать код **11010000 10110100 00000000 00000000** Что вроде бы верно. Но если так сконструированную строку передать на wcout то оно выведет крокозябры и иероглифы.

Сайт https://sites.google.com/site/nathanlexwww/tools/utf8-convert тоже говорит что кодировка буквы 'д' верна.

Тогда нужно посмотреть что из себя представляет
std::wstring wstr = L"добро";
Как выяснилось её внутреннее представление вообще не является utf8 (хотя сам исходник сохранен именно в этой кодировке)

символу 'д' там соответствует **00110100 00000100 00000000 00000000**

**А теперь ряд вопросов**
1. Правильно ли я понимаю что никакие манипуляции со стандартными наборами локалей как такие:

```
locale::global(std::locale("") );
wcout.imbue(std::locale());
```

Не должны влиять на байтовое/битовое представление велечин которые будут присвоены таким образом

```
std::wstring = L"добро"
```

?

2. Debian 8, gcc - все стандартное, стандартная локаль ru_RU.UTF-8 в системе и консоли, исходный код сохранен в UTF-8. В какой кодировке в памяти программы будет сохранена строка `std::wstring = L"добро"` ?
3. Есть ли возможность сделать так чтобы `std::wstring = L"добро"` сохранялась именно в utf8 а не в непонятный формат?

Мне почему-то сейчас думается что в g++ должна быть какая-то опция возможно для чтобы он работал с utf-8, а по дефолту он L"добро" во что-то другое преобразует.

4. правильно ли я конструирую wchar_t символы для x86-64?
5. Есть ли какие-то легковесные библиотеки, которые, вкомпиляясь статически в проект не сильно его утяжелят, обеспечивают высокоуровневый и простой синтаксис наподобии такого же std::wstring = makeUTF8Str(const std::string&) - и без всяких непонятных манипуляций с актуализацией шаблонов wstring_convert и кучей других приседаний?

весь код по которому я пытаюсь понять utf-8 [здесь](https://pastebin.com/4E3nuNcM)

Ребят, если желаете помочь ответом то давайте по существу, а не просто ради флейма как сейчас есть один из ответов ниже - который не отвечает ни на однин из поставленных вопросов, но хочет узнать о "выходе за границы стринга" :)

Comment: я вот не пойму в вашем коде: почему вы делаете так: `ByteMap((char*)(str.c_str()), 5*4)` для простого стринга? Как я понял, второй параметр у вас это количество байт? Так? Но почему оно у вас равно 20?

Comment: для просто стринга можно было бы так: std::wcout << L"string_utf8\n"<< ByteMap(str.c_str(), str.size()) << endl << endl; этот класс на скорую руку создан для понимания того что внутри строк. Поэтому удобством интерфейса он не отличается. А 5*4 - это 5 cимволов по sizeof(wchar_t) каждый

Comment: *" Код буквы 'Д' внезависимости от любых манипуляций с локакалью (или отсутствием этих манипуляций) есть 1101000010110100 Правильно?"* Нет, не правильно. У буквы `Д` такой код будет только в кодировке UTF-8. При преобразовании в одну из кодировок, которые могут храниться в wchar_t, код будет другой. Локаль - это штуки типа формата даты, а за коды букв отвечает только кодировка. Легковесныех библиотек нет, есть только ICU

Comment: VTT, да, но речь именно о utf8, т.е. мы например читаем из файла utf8 в озу программы, и я спрашиваю что не повлияет ли какие-то манипуляции с выставлением локали в программе на то что код 'д' в памяти будет другим (ну опуская конечно на данном этапе вопроса - учитвание того что код д - это два байта а в озу под него на моей платформе выделится 4 байта, и вопросы порядка байт). Т.е. мы работаем только с utf-8 другие кодировки не рассматриваем, пользуем внутри программы wchar_t исключительно как переменная для utf8 кодировок, а не любых других широких кодировок.

Comment: Код символов от локали никак не зависит. А код символа `д` в кодировке UTF-8 занимает строго два байта и не зависит от порядка байт. Кроме того, текст в кодировке UTF-8 не может хранится в wchar_t, так как это побайтовая кодировка. Преобразования, которые вы сделали, запихнув два байта UTF-8 в один wchar_t, невалидные.

Comment: vtt, не совсем понял про побайтовую https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB - вроде говорят что она для широких символов. Но да имеет фиксированный размер, но достаточных чтобы влезли все utf-8 (в моем случае там например только латница и кириллица есть). Вот я и думал запихать туда её. Ведь каждый символ utf-8 строки должен как-то быть представлен каким-то одним универсальным объектом, в не зависимости от того занимает ли он 1, 2, 3 или более байт на свое описание. Чтобы с ним можно было удобно работать wstr[0]==L'ы'

Comment: и вот оператор [] возвращал бы этот wchar_t а оператор == сравнивал бы два wchar_t между собой, но проблема в том что L'ы' компилятор делает не utf-8кодировке когда иницализирует строку, а в непойми какой

Comment: Правильно, L'ы' - это не UTF-8, коды символов, записываемые в одной из кодировок для wchar_t будут другие. А удобно работать навроде `wstr[0]==L'ы'` даже при правильной кодировке не получится.

Comment: Про литералы и состояние Unicode в C++ я писал в [этой статье](http://scrutator.me/post/2013/12/29/various_literals.aspx). Правда, приведённое там преобразование между UTF-8 и Wide characters стало deprecated в C++17, но общее понимание проблем можно из статьи получить. Вкратце: с Unicode в C++ всё очень плохо, нужно использовать сторонние библиотеки. Например, [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org) или [CsString](https://github.com/copperspice/cs_string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, резюмируя ответы на вопросы:

1. Да, правильно.

   2. Utf-32. Не смотря на то что в моём линуксе дефолтом кодировка utf8 в системе, и исходник сохранён в ней, сам копилятор когда
      читает такое L”строка” в озу данную строку занесёт к кодировке
      utf-32. С этим помог разобраться сайт, который показывает все
      варианты кодировок для конкретного символа
      https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0424/index.htm
   3. Такой возможности не нашел, т.е. std::wstring = L"добро" на прямую такого нет чтобы в какой-то свой формат, но т.к. это си++
      можно переопределить оператор = - но это лишняя трата времени причем
      бесполезно, т.к. неявные преобразования не есть хорошо, особенно для
      тех кто потом будет сопровождать код
   4. Правильно, но не нужно, ибо конкретная система работает с utf32
   5. Есть, большое спасибо пользователю [ixSci](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15146/ixsci) за его ответ, да и за его блог (который я иногда находил через поисковик и читал)

Лично я выбрал эту библиотеку http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/, она очень проста (как по реализации и размеру, чтобы подключить к проекту в любой ос нужно всего один хедер, а сама библиотека всего в 4 файлах кода) в добавок кросплатформенна.

С этой библиотекой utf8 можно преобразовать так сказать в нативный для бинарника создаваемого моим компилятором вид очень просто:

```
wstring toUtf8(const string &str) {
    std::wstring ret;
    utf8::utf8to32(str.begin(), str.end(), back_inserter(ret));
    return ret;
}
```

и иметь возможность корректно перемещаться посимвольно по строке, и сравнивать как буквы так и строки if(mystr == L"g++ широкая строка")

Comment: кстати можно сразу в wstr записывать, а не вектор, просто в мане с офф.сайта либы именно так было :)